# XChange bitfinex ticker Java example code not working

Tags: java

Hi I'm trying to use bitfinex ticker from xchange library from here: http://knowm.org/open-source/xchange/

I'm trying to use one of their example codes but it's not working for me

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.knowm.xchange.Exchange;
import org.knowm.xchange.ExchangeFactory;
import org.knowm.xchange.bitfinex.v1.BitfinexExchange;
import org.knowm.xchange.bitfinex.v1.dto.marketdata.BitfinexTicker;
import org.knowm.xchange.bitfinex.v1.service.BitfinexMarketDataServiceRaw;
import org.knowm.xchange.currency.CurrencyPair;
import org.knowm.xchange.dto.marketdata.Ticker;
import org.knowm.xchange.service.marketdata.MarketDataService;

/**
 * Demonstrate requesting Order Book at Bitfinex
 */
public class TickerDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Use the factory to get Bitfinex exchange API using default settings
    Exchange bitfinex = ExchangeFactory.INSTANCE.createExchange(BitfinexExchange.class.getName());
    //Exchange bitfinex = ExchangeFactory.INSTANCE.createExchangeWithoutSpecification(BitfinexExchange.class.getName());

    // Interested in the public market data feed (no authentication)
    MarketDataService marketDataService = bitfinex.getMarketDataService();

    generic(marketDataService);
    raw((BitfinexMarketDataServiceRaw) marketDataService);

}

private static void generic(MarketDataService marketDataService) throws IOException {

    // Get the latest ticker data showing BTC to USD
    Ticker ticker = marketDataService.getTicker(CurrencyPair.BTC_USD);

    System.out.println("generic " + ticker.toString());
}

private static void raw(BitfinexMarketDataServiceRaw marketDataService) throws IOException {

    // Get the latest ticker data showing BTC to USD
    BitfinexTicker ticker = marketDataService.getBitfinexTicker("btcusd");

    System.out.println("raw " + ticker.toString());

    }
}
```

Error during compilation:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.knowm.xchange.ExchangeFactory.<init>(ExchangeFactory.java:21)
at org.knowm.xchange.ExchangeFactory.<clinit>(ExchangeFactory.java:18)
at TickerDemo.main(TickerDemo.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 3 more
```

I have uploaded libraries to my project, cant see any errors on imports so it should be working fine but for some reason its not. Using Intellij

Comment: Sorted it out when created project with Maven, Im new user here and not sure if i should remove the question or just leave it here in case someone have similiar problem?

Comment: this would help me a lot if you gave some more insights on how you actually fixed it, because I have the same problem